# How to make radiobutton and checkbox displays like they do as in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

In IE11, checkbox and listbox are displayd like this as default :

[image]

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="radio" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="radio" />
</body>
</html>
```

Can I make them display like in IE8 by adding custom style CSS :

[image]

[image]

[image]

P/s : I notice in IE8, when hover over a checkbox, there are some events which will make the checkbox to change a little different so we know the mouse pointer is currently over the control, but in IE11 nothing happens when I hove the cursor over the checkbox, can I make this happen in IE11 too?

Comment: Without changing the "input" tags with nested divs (and css), there's no way to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not possible on these elements. You will have to use another element to mimic the look, perhaps scrolling the actual element off the page and using the label for attribute for the click event.

Answer (score -1):

-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;

These rules to can exclude browser styles from webkit browsers.
And add your specific custom rules / styles for input